# How can I distribute my Blackberry App with SQLite pre-populated

Tags: javascript, sqlite, blackberry, cordova

I am currently creating a new app using PhoneGap and have currently completed my iOS version. I had previously pre-populated a database added into the www folder and simply used db.openDatabase to load my database up.

However, I was wondering is the same possible when running through a Blackberry, as when I have attemped to run this through the simulator it seems to be crashing.

Also, creating the database on the fly when the app is first run is not an option for me due to the size of the data and the need for dynamic data.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: They may be using an old version of sqlite. Check http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_legacy_file_format to know how create a file compatible with older versions of sqlite. Maybe That work.